# How can I figure out the sequence for these series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to figure out the sequence of these series

**K=$1$** :$ 1,1$

**K=$2$** : $1,2,1$

**K=$3$** : $1,3,3,1$

**K=$4$** : $1,4,6,4,1$

**K=$5$** : $1,5,10,10,5,1$

**K=$6$** : $1,6,15,20,15,6,1$

**K=$7$** : $1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1$

**K=$8$** : $1,8,28,56,70,56,28,8,1$

It appears that the number of elements in each sequence is **$K+1$**.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Look up *binomial coefficients*.

Comment: You will also find information under the name Pascal's triangle. These are very common numbers and will likely become familiar to you. They have many interesting properties and are well worth investigating.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007318

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{k = n :} \: 1, \: \frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}, \: \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}, \cdots , \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}, \cdots, \: \frac{n!}{(n-1)!(n-(n-1))!}, \: \frac{n!}{n!(n-n)!}$

Here is your sequence, it has k+1 terms, and the j-th term is like the form $\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}$ for $ 0 \leq j \leq n$

In where $j! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdots j$ if $j≥1$, and $0! = 1$

Comment: Thanks for you all!

Answer (score 0):

In $k=1$, when you add $1$ and $1$, you get $2$, which is the second term of $k=2$.

In $k=2$, when you add $1$ and $2$, you get $3$, which is the second term of $k=3$

Similarly, in $k=7$, when you add $7$ and $21$, you get $28$ (in $k=8$). When you add $21$ and $35$, you get $56$ (in $k=8$).

Are you able to figure out the pattern now?